# How to select some kind of elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, element

I have two kind of `<textarea>`:

1) Posts: `id="textarea-post-{id}"`

2) Comments: `id="textarea-cmnt-{id}"`

For example, here is all `textarea` in the page:

```
<textarea id="textarea-post-1"></textarea>
<textarea id="textarea-cmnt-1"></textarea>
<textarea id="textarea-cmnt-2"></textarea>
<textarea id="textarea-cmnt-3"></textarea>
<textarea id="textarea-post-2"></textarea>
<textarea id="textarea-cmnt-4"></textarea>
<textarea id="textarea-cmnt-5"></textarea>
<textarea id="textarea-post-3"></textarea>
<textarea id="textarea-cmnt-6"></textarea>
```

Ok well, Now I want to know, how can I select all the **post kind** textarea ?
These:

```
<textarea id="textarea-post-1"></textarea>
<textarea id="textarea-post-2"></textarea>
<textarea id="textarea-post-3"></textarea>
```

Comment: @SheraliTurdiyev actually I just can select all textarea like this: `$('textarea')`, or specific id like this: `$('#textareaid')`.

Comment: If you give `textarea-post-{id}` the class `textarea-post` and `textarea-cmnt-{id}` the class `textarea-cmnt` you can use `$(".textarea-post")`

Comment: You should really add an appropriate class to these elements so you don't need to use such messy selectors.

Comment: @Sajad. just use this `$('[id^=textarea-post]')...`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a css selector with `querySelectorAll` like this :

```
document.querySelectorAll('[id^="textarea-post"]');
```

The `^=` operator will look for every element with an id starting with `textarea-post`.

jQuery version :

```
$('[id^="textarea-post"]');
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
console.log($('textarea[id*=post]'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="textarea-post-1"></textarea>
<textarea id="textarea-cmnt-1"></textarea>
<textarea id="textarea-cmnt-2"></textarea>
<textarea id="textarea-cmnt-3"></textarea>
<textarea id="textarea-post-2"></textarea>
<textarea id="textarea-cmnt-4"></textarea>
<textarea id="textarea-cmnt-5"></textarea>
<textarea id="textarea-post-3"></textarea>
<textarea id="textarea-cmnt-6"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 3):

Check this.

```js
$('textarea[id^="textarea-post"]').click(function(){
  $(this).css('background-color', 'green');
});
```

```css
textarea[id^="textarea-post"]{
  background-color:red;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="textarea-post-1"></textarea>
<textarea id="textarea-cmnt-1"></textarea>
<textarea id="textarea-cmnt-2"></textarea>
<textarea id="textarea-cmnt-3"></textarea>
<textarea id="textarea-post-2"></textarea>
<textarea id="textarea-cmnt-4"></textarea>
<textarea id="textarea-cmnt-5"></textarea>
<textarea id="textarea-post-3"></textarea>
<textarea id="textarea-cmnt-6"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is howw you select all textarea with `id` value that starts with `textarea-post-`:

```
$("textarea[id^='textarea-post-']")
```

Similarly,

```
$("textarea[id^='textarea-cmnt-']")
```

**Working Example:**

```js
console.log($("textarea[id^='textarea-post-']"));  // outputs all textarea with `id` value starting with `textarea-post-`.
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="textarea-post-1"></textarea>
<textarea id="textarea-cmnt-1"></textarea>
<textarea id="textarea-cmnt-2"></textarea>
<textarea id="textarea-cmnt-3"></textarea>
<textarea id="textarea-post-2"></textarea>
<textarea id="textarea-cmnt-4"></textarea>
<textarea id="textarea-cmnt-5"></textarea>
<textarea id="textarea-post-3"></textarea>
<textarea id="textarea-cmnt-6"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('[id^="textarea-post-"]').each(function () {
  $(this).val();
});
```

This will get all `textarea-post-` then itterate through each one and get the value `$(this).val();`

Answer (score 1):

This is what you are looking for `$('[id^="textarea-post-"]')`. 
Starts with selector `^=` is a proper approach for your case.

Answer (score 0):

Its very easy by CSS using [attribute$=value] Selector will do the trick.

```
textarea[id$="post"]{
 color:red
}
textarea[id$="cmnt"]{
 color:blue
}
```

Comment: I'm talking about js (or jquery), not css

Answer (score 0):

you can use jquery lib and use its function
[Jquery library link here](http://%22https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3)

```js
$(‘p:nth-child(3)) gets the 3rd <p> element of the parent. n=even, odd too.
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Instead of p use textarea